# Nested Select Mongodb query error

Tags: php, sql, mongodb

I am trying to convert the following example from mysql to Mongodb.

However, i am stuck at a point. Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

**SQL Query:**

```
$cmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM pkt_tbl WHERE m_out_port= " . $out_port . " AND m_time<=" . $selPointX . " AND m_time>=" . $startTime . ") AS pkt_tbl WHERE m_in_port=" . $i;
```

**Mongodb Query (WHAT I TRIED):**

```
    $find_query = array('m_out_port'=>$out_port, 'm_in_port'=>$i,'m_time'=>array('lte' => $selPointX, 'gte'=>$startTime));
$find_projections = count();
$result = $table->find($find_query, $find_projections);
```

**What I tried (Aside from Code)**

I read the mongodb docs and other PHP.NET (Mongodocs) but still couldn't find relevant solution.

I am not sure if it's right/I am going in right path.

Please elucidate.
- R

Comment: Please check. OOps. I changed it now. Does it look alright or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Please don't change your question so much after it was answered. Rather use comments in case it doesn't work or you have further issues. Your error now is that you miss '$' in '$gte' and '$lte'.

Comment: Because now the answer is answering different question, you see...

Comment: Thank you for the inputs.I am quite new here but you are right! :)

Comment: Looks like upon execution, I'm facing an error at `$find_projections = count();` Is it appropriate to use Select count(*) in this way? @sashkello

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$gte` and `$lte` keywords for date range (greater or equals to and less than or equals to). Now you select only those records where date is equal to `startTime` and `selPointX` (so if they are different, you get no values returned).

Change your time conditions to:

```
'm_time'=>array('$lte' => $selPointX, '$gte'=>$startTime)
```

If you need those times not inclusive, then use `$gt` and/or `$lt`.

Comment: Looks like upon execution, I'm facing an error at `$find_projections = count();` Is it appropriate to use Select count(*) in this way?

Comment: I think you just need $result = $table->count($find_query)

Comment: This is my final query, and I am still getting an error. If i comment the `$result` variable then the page works fine. (I am testing the query in a seperate php file)

`$find_query = array('m_out_port'=>$out_port,'m_time'=>$selPointX, 'm_time'=>array('$gte'=>$startTime));
    echo $find_query;
  $result = $table -> $find($find_query);
  echo $result;`

Any inputs? And thanks @sashkello for your help

Comment: 1. 'm_time' issue is not completely right (selects time = selPointX and > startTime). 2. find($find_query) instead of $find($find_query)

Comment: Alright. thank you. I'll try to see if it works again. I'll return back with the result.